# MVC framework error in second level directory

Tags: php, remote-file-inclusion

i am building an mvc framework to manage my projects i have my htaccess file configured as this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mymvc/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

things are fine with the project folders when i test. but when i go one directory further (admin/) i get this error

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\wamp\www\mymvc\Admin\library\View.php on line 17
```

please can someone help me out?

Comment: What in View.php file?

Answer (score 0):

The error itself tells you exactly what's wrong. You are attempting to `require` a file via the `http://` scheme but this is disabled in your configuration.

If the file is actually local, you should not be using the `http://` scheme but rather a local filesystem path, eg

```
require 'path/to/some/file';
```

If the required file is remote, you will need to change your server config (`php.ini`). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

Comment: thanks! Made amendments and it now working. thanks for your time and support